# How to pass variables to template without routing in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have some issue with passing variables to a template. I want to output all tags in my test website on every page. In order to do this i create a new method in the controller, which fetch all tags and pass them to the template:

```
  function sidebarAction(){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $tags = $em->getRepository('MyBlogBundle:Blog')->getTags();
    return $this->render('::base.html.twig',array('tags'=>$tags));

}
```

But then occure there is an error:

> Variable "tags" does not exist in ::base.html.twig at line 90

I tried another template but this didn't solved my problem. If I create a new route with a separate page - all works fine! But this is not what I need. 
What I do wrong?

Comment: If i understand you well, that's what you're looking for: http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_view.html#embedding-other-controllers

Comment: Instead of using embedded controller, you should create a Twig extension  for better testability.